# Would reusable rockets render the idea of space elevators useless?

Tags: reuse, space-elevator, economics

With the expected advances in reusable rocket technology within the next decade, will constructing a space elevator become meaningless? Or will it still be way cheaper, safer and convenient to use them?

Comment: Space elevators are science fiction at this point @harsh99. We don't have the technology or know-how to build one, so how would we know if it's going to be cheaper to use one or not?

Comment: @GdD according to projected costs?

Comment: The first chapter of the new book "Soonish" discusses various proposed technologies for cheap space exploration. You can find the pros and cons of reusable rockets and space elevators there.

Comment: @harsh99 none of the materials that we have observed in universe or have some theory on how they might me made are sufficiently strong to make a space elevator on Earth (Moon or Mars is a different case). It's possible that with more knowledge about physics we'll find a material that works (but we can't estimate the costs of that because we can't imagine such a material yet), and it's possible that with more knowledge about physics we'll find out that such materials are impossible.

Comment: @Peteris How many things we previously thought should be physically impossible turned out to be possible? This is something I'm pretty sure we'll achieve in a few decades.

Comment: @harsh99 it's certainly possible that we'll find out something new after a few decades, but until we have *some* idea of the physical processes that might make so strong materials, we can't make even remote estimates on what activities, resources and thus what costs would be required to make one. E.g. if carbon nanotubes might be sufficient, then  estimating the future cost of mass-producing carbon nanotubes would help; but since they can't ever be sufficient (the C-C molecular bond is not strong enough) then that estimate doesn't help us say how much effort that future material might need.

Comment: @Peteris About that, aren't DNT sufficient?

Comment: And it *is* worth noting that there are just as many things that we thought that might be possible and with more knowledge in physics turned out to be permanently impossible. Thermodynamics conservation laws put a big stop to all kinds of ideas on how to achieve perpetual motion or free energy; relativity put a stop to imagined high-speed travel by finding out the light speed barrier.

Comment: There's a limit to how strong the strongest possible material can be - science doesn't *improve* that limit, science *finds out* where the limit lies by approaching it as closely as possible; and the true limit (which we don't know yet) might be sufficient for an earth-sized space elevator, or it might well be below that, as far as we know.

Comment: As far as I understand, there's no current estimates that DNTs are sufficient, that still needs to be investigated - I didn't find any good estimates of their tensile strength that would be sufficiently high. It's worth noting that DNTs are reported to be noticably better than *currently practical* carbon nanotube fibres, not that they're better than the theoretical perfect no-defect single tube that's used in discussions of space elevator viability. DNTs are a way of getting closer to that ideal maximal strength C-C-C-C bond thread, but not beyond that.

Comment: Space Elevators require a lot less energy to lift a given mass to orbit.  In the long run it will be cheaper.  A lot!

Comment: @GdD I think it depends on where the space elevator is built.  As I understand it, there is no known material strong enough to build an earth based space elevator.  However, (as I understand) commercially available materials are strong enough to build a mars based space elevator.  So I would be more confident in a cost estimate for a mars space elevator than an earth one.  Given what I know (which is probably wrong), disposable rockets are the cost effective choice.

Comment: Rockets are not nearly as cost efficient no matter how one counts, (if we ever figure out how to build a space elevator in practice.)

Answer (score 29):

## A Space Elevator would still be amazingly useful

The two factors that come to mind are forms of power and scale:

#### Power

With a space elevator connected to the ground, you could use the energy in your power grid to lift everything up. By doing this, we can use green and renewable energies.

With rockets, baring any massive advancements, we are restricted to using chemical energy. So not only to we have to specifically manufacture the fuel, but the entire process maybe less efficient. Not to mention the environmental effects of burning millions of tons of methane if you want something big in orbit.

#### Scale

Most likely, we'd be able to bring much larger masses into orbit at a time with a space elevator. Even with SpaceX's BFR system, a large ship in orbit has to refuel multiple time to get anywhere. With a space elevator, we could potentially bring a fully fueled ship (without any need to have in-atmosphere propulsion on-board) into orbit in one go.

All this being said, we still need *HUGE* advances in material science for any space elevator to be viable.

Comment: Another advantage worth considering, but too minor for its own answer--a space elevator's slower ascent profile also has a much kinder acceleration/vibration environment for its payloads, reducing engineering and construction costs for several payload types.

Comment: Many launch systems don't burn methane but liquid oxygen + liquid hydrogen which creates nothing but water vapor. But the energy use argument applies here too, of course.

Comment: Not only can you use energy from the electric grid to lift stuff into orbit, you can recover most of that energy (minus friction losses &c) when you lower it back to the surface.  Indeed you could turn it into a power generator by docking a small asteroid to it, and lowering pieces to the ground :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Wouldn't that only work with things that were already in almost exactly the right orbit? That seems like a pretty rare occurance

Comment: What about maintenance?

Comment: Space elevators are amazingly *useless*. Mostly. As for getting things into orbit they won't save much energy, since lifting is a small part compared to going to orbital velocity. (And they require high amounts of unobtainium to begin with).

Comment: Space elevators can actually get things in orbits, but only higher orbits. If you drop something off at GEO it will actually stay there, and you will have some kind of an orbit as you get closer. Also, no current launch system uses methane, most common is kerosene or hydrogen.

Comment: Space elevators must be at the equator, and there's not much of a power grid -- or any other First World infrastructure, for that matter -- on or near the equator.

Comment: @BeB00: Obviously you'd have to move things (like small asteroids) to the right orbit to dock with the elevator, but that's easy enough to do.

Comment: @Jens: Elevators would save a LOT of energy.  If you launch something with a rocket, most of the energy is spent lifting the fuel.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation or reflect that the Saturn V used for lunar missions delivered about 4% of its liftoff mass to Earth orbit.  OTOH, if your space elevator uses electric power, the "fuel" is essentially massless.

Comment: @Jens I think a crucial point you're missing is that a space elevator does _not_ just lift stuff up – that would indeed seem somewhat useless due to “space isn't high, but it's _fast_” thing. A space elevator lifts things up and, while doing so, also accelerates them, because the angular frequency is constant, so speed depends linearly on radius. — Even if it did only lift stuff out of Earth's gravity potential, that would be very useful though: the reason you need to be so fast in LEO is that this is still very deep in the potential well. Further out, you also don't need as much speed.

Comment: @jamesqf but then you're spending energy in the form of rocket fuel (which needs to be put into space anyway) to capture these asteroids. I suspect that again, the region where the energy gain exceeds the energy loss is fairly small, and I would imagine that there are very very few asteroids in that region.

Comment: @BeB00: You don't need rocket fuel to move an asteroid.  All you need is a mass driver or ion engine, with a nuclear reactor (or solar power, if you're patient :-)) to provide power.  You use some of the material of the asteroid itself as reaction mass.

Comment: @jamesqf ok, but you're still going to be using energy in some form. I'm just skeptical that there are more than like 5 asteroids total that could ever be close to feasible for this method. I'm not aware of any asteroids orbiting earth (except one or two earth trojans), so you would have to get an asteroid from somewhere else in the solar system to an exact orbit around earth. This seems highly implausible. *Maybe* this would be useful for deorbiting manmade satellites, but I dont think you would ever get a net gain from an asteroid.

Comment: @BeB00: I don't know if there'd be a net gain, but that's not really the point.  Anything you do bring down the space elevator generates electricity.  If you bring back more than you send up - e.g. space based mining & manufacturing - you generate more electricity (ignoring losses) than you use sending stuff up.  Just the opposite of a rocket, where you use large amounts of energy lifting the rocket and fuel, only to see it turn to heat on reentry.

Answer (score 15):

Rockets suffer from the tyrrany of the rocket equation.  While a reusable rocket is great, you need to burn a *lot* of propellant for each kg of mass to reach orbital velocity.

A space elevator can steal momentum from the planet itself to provide the speed required to reach orbital velocity (or beyond).

In general, fast energy expenditure is less efficient than slow.  Elevators allow efficient energy (solar power or whatever) to be used to lift cargo (electric climbing cars).  Rockets require high energy density fuel (rocket fuel) to be burned *and lifted to the spot where it is used* by earlier rocket fuel.

The 'hard' part of a space evevator is the materials science required; we lack matter that has the tensile strength required on human scales in a controlled lab, let alone industrial scales in the open air.  Once that is solved, we have the problem of building it in place, building a factory in orbit, dodging debris and weather, designing lifters, etc, each of which are problems larger in scale than the Apollo Program.

Reusable rockets would reduce the cost of lifting stuff to orbit, but the fuel costs would remain high.  Such cheap launch technology would open up the possibility of building (expensive) factories in space, and/or move asteroids into position to provide the other end of the space elevator.  So quite possibly they are a prerequisite for the elevator.

Once you have the elevator, lifting to orbit energy cost plummets and it becomes basically electricity (at current prices of 1$ per kg to orbital velocity).  Currently it costs on the order of 10000\$ per kg.  Reliable reusable rockets might cut that down, but probably to 1000\$ or 100\$s of dollars per kg, not single-dollars per kg.

Space elevators have limited capacity, so while the energy costs might be 1\$ per kg, prices may be similar to competing technology until demand saturates the pipe.  However, the first space elevator can then be used to build the second, and you'd have something similar to an industrial revolution exponential economic expansion as the cost of reaching space converges on the energy cost.

At 100\$-1000\$/kg to orbit, space travel of humans requires a small fortune per person.  Space may open up to *industry* and robots, but not to migration.

At 1\$/kg to orbit, and 2\$/kg to Lithobraking on Mars (not including travel time), the solar system becomes our back yard.

Comment: LOL @ lithobraking!  Hopefully that's not the deceleration plan when we *are* sending humans to Mars :)

Comment: @Brian RyanMars offers premium transport options at a higher price point.

Comment: @Yakk  "each of which are problems larger in scale than the Apollo program" Really?

Comment: @harsh99 Yes, by far.  The Apollo program was to move a single small craft to the moon, land, take off, and get back to Earth.  We are talking about building a megastructure, something in many ways bigger than humanity has ever built, mostly in outer space (unless you count systems like interstate highways or rail systems as single structures).  Building a beanstalk on Earth (lying down, say) would be a ridiculously huge undertaking; building it in orbit has "minor details" that are themselves huge.

Comment: @Yakk this idea might sound really ridiculous at this stage. How would it go for autonomous robots which take in atmospheric carbon and turn it into the required structure? They will only require to be sent up once and then they can slowly glide down with appropriate ground control. Of course, developing them would itself be a cost issue, but I think that way it should be comparatively cheaper.

Comment: I'm also having some alternative ideas for the climbers after playing Halo 5. Check out this video: [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8zbr6saLXAhWJvo8KHV24CDMQtwIIODAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D-w44T34I_mE&usg=AOvVaw1Q1j1WEeI5NROFMBvirnbZ)

Comment: @harsh99 The practical way to build a beanstalk is to start with mass in geosynchronous orbit and extrude structure both down and possibly up.  At the ground, you build a mounting facility (which by itself is a megaengineering project, but minor as part of this project).  Hand-waving difficulty, you dangle the constantly tapering cable down through the atmosphere until it it connected to the mounting facility.  There are precursors to thi kind of technology, like skyhooks and hyde fountains, that may be easier than a full beanstalk yet cheaper than reusable rockets.

Answer (score 12):

Whatever concept of space elevator you want to build, it requires you to transport massive amounts of material into space, so no. Having cheap launch vehicles is actually a requirement to building a space elevator. Whether the elevator could ever break even given its high mass is another matter altogether.

Comment: If we use resources available in space or atmospheric carbon to do it, then?

Comment: @harsh99 lot of equipment would be needed anyway no matter where you get the material from.

Comment: @jkavalik Suppose you have a 3d printer that processes materials from space and prints the structure directly using solar power. Or a similar thing with atmospheric carbon. Would it still be expensive?

Comment: The comments are approaching Worldbuilding.SE ;)

Comment: @harsh99 impossible to know - at that point we might have fusion powered rockets, or not. Too much fi for the sci.

Comment: I specifically prefaced my answer with "Whatever concept of space elevator you want to build" because there are lots of concepts, but they all require enormous amounts of material to be transported to space, generally as a trade-off between technological complexity of the approach to mass required. It's a hard question to answer if you allow for technology that isn't there yet, so I didn't want to go into it.

Answer (score 4):

A space elevator, no matter what sort of unobtanium it's built from or how it works, has one unbeatable advantage over a rocket: the elevator cars don't need to carry their fuel with them.  The vast majority of the energy involved in a rocket launch goes into carrying rocket fuel to ever-higher speeds and altitudes; being able to leave your energy source on the ground is a huge efficiency gain.

The phrase [tyranny of the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) isn't just poetry.

Comment: And if "22500 mile long carbon nanotubes that can hold dozens of tons of weight while not being ripped to shreds by the friction of the crawler" does actually turn out to be unobtanium, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAXGUQ_ewcg a laser which gets at most 2.5% efficiency isn't too much better -- if at all -- than the rocket equation.

Comment: @RonJohn: Not sure exactly how the video derived that, but it was probably considering using PV panels driven by lasers. Very recent research has shown it's possible to create direct rectenna power generation at optical wavelengths, with much greater efficiency at a particular wavelength. Here, that should give a solid fourfold increase in efficiency, or at least 10% assuming the other (unknown) calculations were correct.

Comment: @RonJohn, are lasers the only option?

Comment: @harsh99 you'll have to ask the engineers and scientists who study what would be needed to develop space elevators.  The reason that lasers are given as the energy source is that they are ground-based and thus the crawler won't have to carry the huge extra mass of it's energy source with it (which is the whole purpose of getting rid of rockets).

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting point - the hard part isn't getting *up*, it's going *fast*.

Presumably, since the elevator is tethered to the ground it's already going fast - fast enough to stay in geostationary uh... orbit?

Since by the time whatever you were moving into space got to the top of the elevator, it's going to be going the same speed, it should be a lot easier since you just need to keep moving.

Comment: For small payloads, slowly, one at a time, from one and the same point on the surface at the equator. Logistically very sensitive. Strings are by design highly exposed and unprotected. It is too big and inflexible an investment to be worthwhile. Power can be beamed. Fuel is very cheap and plentiful. Low gravity asteroids one can jump off of in a space suit, so the concept is useless in low gravity and undoable in Earth gravity. The Moon would be the only potential candidate (unless its eccentricity messes that up). If it can be built there without using any carbon (not available on the Moon).

Answer (score 1):

In the book "The Fountains of Paradise", by Arthur C. Clarke, it is mentioned that a space elevator can regenerate some of the electricity it uses to move material up by electronically braking as it brings material down, like regenerative braking on electric cars.

There is also the possibility of actual rescue, should something go wrong.  There is a very intense section of the book that involves a rescue maneuver, which also involves "thinking outside the box".  I'd explain more, but I don't want to drop any spoilers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fountains_of_Paradise

I believe the book also mentions that with the space elevator, you don't need to reach escape velocity until you reach the end of the elevator.  Since that's in space, escape velocity from that point should be considerably less than it is from the surface.  Less air resistance should also make it easier to reach.

Rockets work on a exponential thrust restriction.  The more you want to put into space, the way more fuel you need to lift off.  It's not just that you are lifting 10 lbs into orbit, but you are also lifting the all fuel to get you there.  The rocket crews have to make decisions of how important items are to a mission, because that 10 lbs of cargo may mean something like 10,000 lbs more fuel.  Maybe this is explained by the tyranny of the rocket equation, but I don't have the chops to understand that.

Because there's so much fuel going into a rocket launch, it's expensive.  Electricity, on the other hand, is relatively cheap.  Renewable and nuclear generators have pretty much guaranteed that.  Plus, with the extra height of the space elevator to get past the atmosphere, solar panels might be able to be added to the tower itself, allowing it to generate some of it's own power, beyond the regenerative braking mentioned earlier.

Beyond launch things into space, a space elevator could be a starting point for a ring around the earth, at orbital height.  This could in turn be a platform for a full planet enclosure.  Both ideas are referenced in several books I've read but can't recall right now.  Both have their advantages in economy and beyond.

Going back to "The Fountains of Paradise", it tells about families going for sight seeing trips, including elderly people.  Sightseeing is very big business, and if even the baby and the older generation of a family can join in, then you've really got something that'll draw visitors.   Well, you know, besides being able to see a significant portion of the earth all at once, being "in space", and lots of other "cool factors."

The book also mentions being able to launch capsules in very short order, like multiples a day.  Right now, that's not possible with rockets, even with airplane launched rockets.

The book is basically an essay in how space elevators are pretty much necessary for us to continue to be in space, couched in a science fiction novel.  It's a great book, winning both the Hugo and Nebula awards.  I've enjoyed reading it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Escape velocity is greater than geosynchronous velocity.  The asteroid or whatever at the end of a tether would have to travel a bit *faster* than geosynchronous velocity, because of all the mass *below* the orbit of the asteroid moving at *slower* than (for the altitude of each bit) orbital velocity.  Perhaps this would be close, or at least close enough, to escape velocity to allow easy exit from Earth's gravity well.

But even so, the tether itself would have to be very strong to resist the tension it would have to bear.  A lot of people have suggested that carbon nanotubes would do the trick; I suspect even that would not be enough.

And even if we could invent the materials, how would we construct such a thing?  If we capture an asteroid, put it into low-Earth orbit, and move the materials to it, we would still have to make a connection somehow.  We can't just lower the cable into the atmosphere -- it would be whipping around until we (somehow) grab onto the end and attach it onto the Earth station.

Perhaps we will solve all these problems someday.  But it's a little more difficult than I believe most people think.

Comment: sources would be better than hunches